# PDFBox Custom Text Extraction

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

What is the best way to extend the PDFTextStripper class to extract text paragraph by paragraph. I believe `TextPosition` objects (x,y coordinates) carry enough information to be able to group related text (such as paragraphs) together. However I am not sure which method to override.

On web, mainly I see two methods are being overriden for customization.

- `void processTextPosition(TextPosition text)`
- `writeString(String text, List<TextPosition> textPositions)`

I can use the first one as follows. The `processTextPosition` seems to be called for every character.

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try (PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new File(path))) {
            PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper() {
                @Override
                protected void processTextPosition(TextPosition text) {
                    super.processTextPosition(text);
                    sb.append(text.getUnicode());
                }
            };

            stripper.getText(doc);
            System.out.println(sb.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
```

And the `writeString` seems to be called for each line on the PDF.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try (PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new File(path))) {
            PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper() {

                @Override
                protected void writeString(String text, List<TextPosition> textPositions) throws IOException {
                    for (TextPosition textPosition : textPositions) {
                        sb.append(textPosition.getUnicode());
                    }
                }
            };

            stripper.getText(doc);
            System.out.println(sb.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
```

So what would be the recommended way to split text based on position information?

Comment: What exactly do you want in contrast to the regular output of `PDFTextStripper`?

Comment: @mkl We work on document analysis. It is very important to parse PDF by paragraphs or segments properly with style information before inputting it to our machine learning system. Short plain text does not carry enough information for the ML. Style/formating information also carries a lot of clues to determine headings, persons, list items etc. Since we humans can visually separate paragraphs or related segments visually by their position, I thought we could use this information to parse the PDF properly.

Comment: There unfortunately are no paragraphs in pdfs unless they are tagged accordingly. Whether it is better to take the data in `processTextPosition` or in `writeString` depends on the amount of text processing logic from Pdfbox you want to re-use.

Comment: @mkl Thanks. I want to re-use from PDFBox as much as I can. Do I need to override writeString then?